# How can I setup a multi-tenant SharePoint 2010 portal?

Tags: sharepoint, iis-7.5, portal, multi-tenant

I am trying to deploy a SharePoint Portal (2010) as a muti-tenant application (more than one customer). This means I need to segregate the customer data so that customer 1 cannot see customer 2 info, and vice versa. Each customer should have his own logins, data, and visual theme, not viewable by other clients/customers.

Not sure if this is relevant, but the portal will be hosting Microsoft SCSM Self-Service Web-Portal. This consists of 2 SharePoint sites (WebContent Site + Portal) comprised of some Silverlight Web Parts and some databases in an SQL instance.

My idea is client needs to be logging on using Claims-Based/Forms-Based auth, storing credentials in an SQL database. However, I have no idea how to do this, I have tried following a couple of guides but could not get them to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 offers multi tenancy, because it is being used in Office 365 (well, it's SP2013 now of course). However, this is not easy to set up on premises, it is not possible through the UI.
Harbar has written an excellent guide: http://www.harbar.net/archive/2010/09/14/rational-guide-to-multi-tenancy-with-sharepoint-2010-part-six.aspx

And this guide is also good learning material: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/04/02/sharepoint-2010-multi-tenant-hosting-part-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply. However, I have read through Harbars guide and failed at my attempt. I am willing to try again, but are you aware if the SCSM portal can be incorporated into Harbars solution?